# Validation Getting Failed Even on a right condition

Tags: php, codeigniter

I got stuck here with the codeigniter form validation. Here is my code below.

```
$match_data = $this->input->post('match_data');

        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        foreach($match_data as $roundno => $round_data) {
            foreach ($round_data as $roundtimes => $round_times_data) {
                foreach ($round_times_data as $match_no => $match) {
                    foreach ($match as $games_times => $games) {
                        $this->form_validation->set_rules("match_data[".$roundno."][".$roundtimes."][".$match_no."][".$games_times."][score1]", "score1", "trim|xss_clean|numeric");
                        $this->form_validation->set_rules("match_data[".$roundno."][".$roundtimes."][".$match_no."][".$games_times."][score2]", "score2", "trim|xss_clean|numeric");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

When i am submitting a,b,c or anything like this the validation check is fine. but once i put proper numeric value it still showing me error. Please help me to find out the issue? Here is my input filed code

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="match_data[<?php echo $edit_round_num; ?>][<?php echo $matchtime; ?>][<?php echo $match; ?>][<?php echo $gametime+1; ?>][score1]" value="<?php echo $games_per_match_array_one[$gametime]; ?>" />
</div>
                                                                                                <div class="col-sm-6">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="match_data[<?php echo $edit_round_num; ?>][<?php echo $matchtime; ?>][<?php echo $match; ?>][<?php echo $gametime+1; ?>][score2]" value="<?php echo $games_per_match_array_two[$gametime]; ?>" />
                                                                                                </div>
                                                                                            </div>
```

Comment: 4 foreach loops? Please show complete form. I am sure there is better way than 4 recursive foreach loops.

Comment: My Issue got resolved .. incase of numeric trim|xss_clean not to be given

Comment: It will be resource very consuming app if you don't resolve recursive foreach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of validating `numeric` values validation `trim|xss`_clean doesn't work or needed. So once removed `trim|xss_clean` the code starts working.